# What is a regular expression for removing spaces between uppercase letters, but keeps spaces between words?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

For example, if I have a string like "Hello I B M", how do I detect the space between the uppercase letters but not between the "o" and the "I"?

Basically "Hello I B M" should resolve to "Hello IBM"

So far, I have this:

```
value = "Hello I B M"
value = value.replace(/([A-Z])\s([A-Z])/g, '$1$2')
```

But it only replaces the first instance of a space between two uppercase letters like: "Hello IB M"

--EDIT--

Solution Part 1:

```
 value = value.replace(/([A-Z])\s(?=[A-Z])/g, '$1')
```

Thanks to Renato for the first part of the solution! Just found out if there is a capitalized word AFTER an uppercase letter, it swallows that space as well. How do we preserver the space there?

So "Hello I B M Dude" becomes "Hello IBMDude" instead of "Hello IBM Dude"

Comment: Is there a way to remove the space between 2 uppercase words and/or letters so that Face Book becomes FaceBook?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the regex matches the first time (on `"A B"`), this part of the string in consumed by the engine, so it is not matched again, even though your regex has the global (`'g'`) flag.

You could achieve the expected result by using a positive lookahead (`(?=PATTERN)`) instead, that won't consume the match:

```
value = "Hello I B M"
value = value.replace(/([A-Z])\s(?=[A-Z])/g, '$1')
console.log(value) // Prints "Hello IBM"
```

---

To make it not remove the space if the next uppercase letter is the first in a word, you can increment the lookahead pattern with using a word boundary `\b` to make that restriction:

```
value = "Hello I B M Dude"
value = value.replace(/([A-Z])\s(?=[A-Z]\b)/g, '$1')
console.log(value) // Prints "Hello IBM Dude"
```

**Note**: As [@CasimirHyppolite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) noted, the following letter has to be made optional, or the second regex won't work if the last character of the string is uppercase. Thus, the pattern `([^A-Za-z]|$)`, which can be read as "not a letter, or the end of the string".

**Edit**: Simplify lookahead  from `(?=[A-Z]([^A-Za-z]|$))` to `(?=[A-Z]\b)` as suggested by [@hwnd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2206004/hwnd)

Comment: And if the string is `"Hello I B Groink"`

Comment: Works like a charm... except one thing! I just realized when testing against the titles I'm generating. Strings like "Hello I B M Dude" become "Hello IBMDude" How could I prevent the space between swallowed between the "M" and the "Dude"?

Comment: @StevenYuan - now you're changing the requirements.  You asked to remove any space between two caps.  What is the new rule if you don't want that?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thank you, you are correct. Just added an anchor to make it work with the last character of the string

Comment: @RenatoZannon: But now it doesn't work with the second! What about : `/([A-Z])\s(?=[A-Z](?:[^A-Za-z]|$))/g`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte interesting, it works for me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: You could use `([A-Z])\s(?=[A-Z]\b)`

Comment: @hwnd Oh, I forgot about that, no wonder my regexes turn out unreadable! Thanks, edited the answer

Comment: @Renato Zannon Sometimes the smallest things can be overlooked =)

Comment: I just came back because I realized that the answer wasn't complete, and the question was already answered! Thanks everyone